# How to stop MediaPlayer on Adapter when onBackPressed on Activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview

I Create Multiple Data Adapter where there is a MediaPlayer, everything is working fine only with onBackPressed on Activity my mediaplayer is still playing, how to release mediaplayer when user press back button on activity or finis ?

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed and inside it call mediaplayer.stop()